# Backward .NET compatibility for NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm accustomed to the Java world: it's generally safe to run an application on a newer JRE that has dependent .jars compiled with older versions of Java.

.Net is a bit stricter.  For example, if I build an ASP.NET app with TargetFramework "netcoreapp3.1", then I *MUST* install ASP.Net Core 3.1 runtime on every host server I deploy the app on.  I can't just install .NET 7 on the host server, and expect it to work.  Correct?

Q: What about NuGet packages?  Do I need to install the corresponding .NET or .NET Core runtimes for every NuGet dependency my app uses?

Comment: You might want to read this (section about roll forward): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection. That's about host app, and it defines the runtime used for all dependencies, so you don't need to install anything for them (which makes sense since your app will run on a given runtime together with dependencies, they can't run on separate runtime)

Comment: So you can make your app to run on a newer runtime but you need to explicitly enable that option. You can also build self-contained app which includes the runtime - then you won't need to install runtime on target machine at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Docker, or any other container platform like Kubernetes to manage applications like this. It's designed just to avoid situations like this where your application changes to rely on new assets. So you could just basically change the version by just changing a number in your Dockerfile before build and deploy it like any other upgrade. This method is always best practice today. Just swap server application images on your servers for each deployment, no installations.

Alternatively, you could build your application as self-contained (runtime/executable included in your build).

To answer the question, you need the same runtime as your application targers.